# Some devices can't connect to server using mobile internet

Tags: android

Im facing a really odd problem in my android app. It works well in most devices but there are some (not just one particular device) which fail to connect to my server using mobile internet connection, but can connect using wifi.

I don't own any device with that problem so i can't debug it, however i know that the device sends a request to the server (or tries to) but doesn't receive a response as it should. The device does have internet connection as it can browse internet using other apps.

I really don't know if posting some code would help at all since it works well in most devices, which means code is ok, and it works well even in older devices.

One of the devices the app is having this problem is a samsung SM-J700M.

Its a vague questions but maybe some of you know about some specific problem in some devices which require some special treat about this.

Comment: So is the problem that a request is not made, or a response is not received?

Comment: Sadly i cant be sure about that. Server works fine, if it receives the request  it will send the response, so i don't know if the app is not sending the request or if the device blocks the response. If i have to bet, the device is not sending.

Comment: some tele-providers uses type of proxy for mobile-data connections, could this be the issue? when ur request is trying to pass through that alleged-proxy it got dropped or redirected or even returns unexpected response

Comment: It may be the cause... but i have the same provider than one of the users having this problem and it works fine in my device. May be some restriction samsung put to some devices in the past? cos i think that all having this problem have samsung devices with old android ver.